# python django get html tag id at the backend

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get html tag id at backend in views.py as well as redirecting to another html page. The html tag id is generated dynamically. Any idea will be helpful

```
{% for getdata in names %}
   
   <li class="nav-item menu-items {% if 'ui-icons' in segment %} active {% endif %}" id="{{ getdata }}" name="ten">
    
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="{{ getdata }}" class="complete_link">
      <span class="menu-icon" id="{{ getdata }}" name="ten">
        <i class="mdi mdi-contacts"  id="{{ getdata }}" name="ten"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="menu-title" id="{{ getdata }}" name="ten"> {{getdata}} </span>
    </a>
  </li>

   {% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. You want custom id and link for each name right?
If so you can create a dictionnary inside the dictionnary you're passing in your request, with an "id" key and a "url" key and the according data.

Comment: hi yes exactly...thanks

Comment: Alright, I'll add the solution as an answer below. If that works please mark it as a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, you can create a dictionnaries inside the dictionnary you're passing in your request, with an "id" key and a "url" key and the according data.

It would look like so:

```py
names = {"1":{"id":id_1,"url":url_1},...}
```